# TSQL - Averaging a result from sp_MSforeachdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sp-msforeachdb

I have hundreds of databases on the same SQL server (SQL2012), they all have the same basic structure and I'm trying to get the average number of 'Contacts' our databases.

I can run a sp_MSforeachdb query that presents a list of how many contacts are in the contacts table, but I need to then average out the result. Any guidance on doing this.

This is the query I've got so far:

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb
'use ?
IF DB_NAME() NOT IN ( "model","tempdb","master","msdb")
select count (CONTACTID) as TotalContacts from contact_tbl '
```

I appreciate it's likely fairly basic stuff, but I'm new here and I've googled the crap out of it and tried a lot of different suggestions from here and other places with no joy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: insert the count in to a table then you can do whatever you like?

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you-

Comment: you can go with temporary table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a temp table. Insert the `Sp_msforeachdb` procedure result into one temp table and find average

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..#avg') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #avg

CREATE TABLE #avg(cnt INT)

INSERT INTO #avg(cnt)
EXEC Sp_msforeachdb
  'use ?
    IF DB_NAME() NOT IN ( "model","tempdb","master","msdb")
    select count (CONTACTID) as TotalContacts from contact_tbl '

SELECT Avg(cnt)
FROM   #test
```

Comment: Thank you Prdp - TSQL is still new ground, but that seems pretty basic (as suspected) - Baby steps.